# IndexOutOfBoundsException na leitura de um InputStream

Tags: java, arquivo, io

segue o trecho do codigo que estou estudando:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/home/rafael/2015.json"); // esse aquivo tem 24 bytes

byte[] result = new byte[(int) stream.getChannel().size()];

int offset = 0;
int read = 0;

while((read = stream.read(result, offset, 8)) != -1){
    offset += read;
}

stream.close();
```

Mas venho recebendo a seguinte exceção:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at br.com.rafael.socket.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Ja verifiquei o meu offset, e ele funciona corretamente. O que pode ser?

-- adicionando um debug

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/home/rafael/2015.json");

byte[] result = new byte[(int) stream.getChannel().size()];

int offset = 0;
int read = 0;

while((read = stream.read(result, offset, 8)) != -1){
    offset += read;

    System.out.println("read: " + read);
    System.out.println("offset: " + offset);
}

System.out.println("o que foi lido? " + new String(result, "UTF-8"));

stream.close();
```

console:

```
read: 8
offset: 8
read: 8
offset: 16
read: 8
offset: 24
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at br.com.rafael.socket.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

-- adicionando resoluçao:

1º diminui o tamanho da leitura pra 1 byte / iteração

```
while((read = stream.read(result, offset += read, 1)) != -1){}
```

2º aumentei o array de resultado em 1 indice

```
byte[] result = new byte[stream.available() + 1];
```

e agora funcionou perfeitamente:

**PORÉM** eu fico com o ultimo indice do meu array `result` com o valor **0**

-- melhor solução

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/home/rafael/2015");

byte[] result = new byte[stream.available()];

int offset = 0;
int read = 0;
int buffer = 256;
int remain = result.length;

while((remain -= read = stream.read(result, offset += read, buffer >= remain ? remain : buffer)) > 0){}         

stream.close();
```

Comment: Você não está fazendo o parsing para que o java consiga ler o conteúdo do json. Tente debugar seu código, colocando um ponto de interrupção no while, e verá que de cara já retorna -1, o causador da exceção, pois o Stream.read está recebendo indice negativo.

Comment: adicionei um debug

Comment: Você não entendeu, releia o que eu comentei, dessa forma você não vai conseguir ler json. Olhe [**esta pergunta no SOEn**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library) e veja, precisa de uma API que faça o parsing.

Comment: não não.. não quero fazer o parser ainda.. quero primeiro ler a string do arquivo.

Comment: Veja se a solução da resposta resolve o problema.

Comment: Na verdade, so quero entender mesmo o comportamento desse método. É apenas um estudo.

Answer (score 0):

Troque o tamanho adicionado ao array de byte, o valor setado é menor do que deveria ser, então conforme vai iterando, ao chegar a certo valor, acontece o `IndexOutOfBoundsException` utilize o método read()

```
byte[] result = new byte[stream.read()];
```

> Mas caso ainda quiser o valor anterior, em vez de utilizar

```
byte[] result = new byte[(int) stream.getChannel().size()];
```

use

```
byte[] result = new byte[stream.available()];
```

Comment: Na verdade o problema é com o OFFSET mesmo. Quando o segundo parametro do metodo read é 0, a exceção não é jogada. Porém o array result vai estar errado.

Comment: Resolvi, mas não entendi o pq ainda. Adicionei um espaco a mais no array de resultado e funcionou: `byte[] result = new byte[stream.available() + 1];`

Comment: Sim. Fiquei nessa duvida na hora que testei, testei sem o controle fino (offset, length) e funcionou sem problemas, mas acabei não testando a alteração do offset, mas enfim. Poste aqui então, em como fez para resolver :]

Comment: Mas funciona em qualquer situação, com tamanho diferente do arquivo por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, mas pra isso preciso definir o tamanho da leitura pra 1 byte. Adicionei a resolução na primeira postagem. Dá uma olhada

Comment: Hm, porém esse controle fino, vai sempre depender dessa sincronia, se você alterar no array, vai precisar alterar no read() também.

Comment: O valor no array vai precisar sempre ser = ou > para não ter problemas, um pouco estranho.